# Переводчик языков программированя

Tags: perl

Есть ли онлайн переводчик, который переводит текст программы из одного языка программирования в другой?

Comment: Непонятны перловские исходники? Там такое иногда можно написать, что и человек не всегда разберет.

Comment: Знаю про некоторые такие офф-лайновские. Как-то пробовал такой f2c - с фортрана на С. Гадость жуткая. Так ничего и не заработало.

Comment: Что, и HelloWorld не работает?

Comment: Я вещи посущественнее пробовал. Иначе какой смысл?

Comment: Ещё бы понять зачем. Фортраны-то вроде и натуральные доступны.

Comment: Просто как-то встала задача перевести одну программку с Фортрана на С. Решил для интереса поэкспериментировать. Ничего не получилось.  Хотя программа не такая уж сложная была. Переписал руками за пару вечеров. Потом еще парочку программ пробовал. Одна заработала, но работала как черепаха. Там еще какие-то свои библиотеки подключаются... В общем, мрак.

Comment: В результате Вы теперь знаете, что фортрановские программы на Си лучше не переписывать. И это правильно! (Они десятилетиями шлифовались)

Comment: Почему? Переписал и все заработало отлично. А программа была совсем не такая старая. Около месяца ей было.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретней спрашивайте, пожалуйста. Любой компилятор переводит программу с исходного языка на машинный (или ассемблер, или C, или другой backend). Кнутовский TeX написан на языке web (для которого есть переводчики на C и Паскаль). Есть упомянутый выше f2c. Есть [Pascal-to-C](http://www.ccrnp.ncifcrf.gov/~toms/p2c/) (В линуксах идёт в пакетах). Есть масса других вариантов, включая DSL -- domain-specific language. Что конкретно Вас интересует?

Comment: Зачем давать ответ-вопрос? Можно было и комментарием ограничиться

Comment: Побоялся за размер.

Comment: Хм.Ну так два напишите...:)